# Why the statement of one of the spectral theorems involves an integral rather than a sum?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, unbounded-operators

My question is about [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Spectral_subspaces_and_projection-valued_measures) regarding projection-valued measures.

Suppose $H$ is a separable Hilbert space (in many cases we are just concerned about the separable case). Suppose $A$ is an unbounded self-adjoint operator on $H$. Then there is a **projection valued measure(PVM)** $\mu^A$ on $\sigma(A)$ such that
$$
\int_{\sigma(A)} \lambda d\mu^A (\lambda)=A.
$$

Now, I am wondering about one thing: by the definition of PVM, for $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in \sigma(A)$, $\mu^A(\lambda_1)(H)$ (range of the projection) and $\mu^A(\lambda_2)(H)$ are orthogonal subspaces of $H$. Since $H$ is separable, there can be countably many $\lambda$ for which $\mu^A(\lambda)(H)\neq\{0\}$. Therefore, **the integral above could be actually written as a sum.**

However, sometimes, I find out that, although it is clear that we just need to consider the case where $H$ is separable, the above theorem is still written as an integral, rather than a sum.

**Why do we need to write it as an integral?**

Comment: In many ways it is just a sum. But how do you propose writing a measure in a sum? Granted one could argue the measure is unnecessary but it makes the math cleaner to reference measure theory.

Comment: Do you conclude that if $H$ is separable and $\{E_{\lambda}:\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\}$ a family of self-adjoint projections on $H$ that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lambda dE_{\lambda}$ can always be written as a sum?? I doubt that.

Comment: @PeterMelech $E_\lambda\neq 0$ for at most countably many $\lambda$ only, so it makes sense to write it as a sum.

Comment: Why do you think that $E_{\lambda_1}\neq E_{\lambda_2}$ for $\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2$?

Comment: @PeterMelech That's NOT what I think. We know that $E_{\lambda_1}=E(\lambda_1)$ and $E_{\lambda_2}$ are orthogonal to each other for $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2$, so if $E_{\lambda_1}=E_{\lambda_2}$ then both of them are $\{0\}$.

Comment: As far as I know, you just have $E_{\lambda_1}E_{\lambda_2}=E_{\operatorname{min}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)}$.

Comment: orthogonal if they are different

Comment: @PeterMelech To clarify, in my last comment, I take $E_{\lambda_i}$ to mean the image of it, $E_{\lambda_i}(H)$.

Comment: Ok, I agree that the set $\{E_{\lambda}(H):\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\}$ must be countable in case $H$ is separable, but you can have that $\{E_{\lambda}:\lambda\in S\}$ for a not-countable subset $S\subset\mathbb{R}$ may contain just one projection

Answer (score 1):

I think you are taking $\mu(\lambda)$ to mean $\mu(\{\lambda\})$, which it is not. In the first case, $\lambda$ is a dummy variable. In the second case it the spectral projection associated with $\{\lambda\}$, which could be $0$ for all $\lambda$. For example, $\mu(S)f=\chi_{S}f$ is the spectral measure associated with multiplication by $\lambda$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. That is,
$$
                          \mu(S)f = \chi_{S}f,\;\;\; f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}).
$$
You would use dummy variable to write $\int \lambda d\mu(\lambda)f$ in order to write $(Mf)=\lambda f(\lambda)$ as an integral. The spectral measure $P$ in this case is $P(S)f = \chi_{S}f$, which is multiplication by the characteristic function of the set $S$. Note that $P(\{\lambda\})=0$ is the $0$ operator because multiplication by $\chi_{\{\lambda\}}=0$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is the $0$ operator.

Comment: I see. I did NOT confuse $\mu(\lambda)$ with $\mu(\{\lambda\})$, but I realise that the intersection of countably many nested infinite-dimensional Hilbert space could be empty. So, union of singletons with zero $\mu$ could have non-zero $\mu$.

Comment: @MaJoad How are you interpreting $\mu(\lambda)$ to believe that $\mu(\lambda)$ would be non-zero only for a countable number of $\lambda$? You must be thinking of $\mu(\{\lambda\})$ or that would not make sense. But the integral is not defined in terms of $\mu(\{\lambda\})$.